Is this correctly written in Hebrew
Trying to express, that a song reflects the current situation in Israel as of right now.
השיר משקף את המצב המורכב במדינת ישראל

I’m voting to close this question because it does not relate to that the site topic or any other known SE site topic.

Hi Alix, welcome to BH.SE - unfortunately this site is all about the analysis of biblical texts, which isn't really related to your question. Please do check out the Site Tour and the Help Center to learn more about what kind of questions to ask here.

It looks OK, but I'm not fluent in modern Hebrew.  You might get better results asking this question at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions.
